# Argparse - differentiate between no options, option invoked, and option invoked with argument?

Tags: python, argparse

As an example:

```
#thing.py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--show", nargs='?', action="store")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

How do I differentiate between the following usages:

```
python thing.py

python thing.py --show

python thing.py --show all
```

Essentially, I want to do different things if:

- The user specifies no options
- The user specifies the "--show" option by itself
- The user specifies "--show all" - with a string / argument.

Using `default="foo"` in add_argument doesn't work because it is always there when tested - I have no way to know if the user actually specified the option "--show" or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `const` kwarg. If the option is not specified, `default` will be used. If the option is provided on its own, `const` will be used. If the option is provided with a value, the value will be used.

Copying from the documentation:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', nargs='?', const='c', default='d')
>>> parser.add_argument('bar', nargs='?', default='d')
>>> parser.parse_args(['XX', '--foo', 'YY'])
Namespace(bar='XX', foo='YY')
>>> parser.parse_args(['XX', '--foo'])
Namespace(bar='XX', foo='c')
>>> parser.parse_args([])
Namespace(bar='d', foo='d')
```

Comment: This is what I needed!  Thank you @mwchase