# Python argparse optional arguments without argument (not store true)

Tags: python, argparse

How do I add an optional argument which has a default value and can be called with another value or which can be called without value (and has the default one).
So I have this argument

```
    parser.add_argument("-a", "--automatic", type=int, default=8)
```

and I would like to be able to call.
`My_script.py -a`   if I want an automatic mode with 8 as argument, but I also want to do for example `My_script.py -a 10` if I want an automatic mode with 10 (or any other number) as argument.
The problem is that I get expected one argument when I run with `My_script.py -a`. If I don't want to specify the 8, I am also not allowed to specify the -a and then I have to run `My_script.py`, which is not what I want.

Comment: If passing nothing is equivalent to passing `-a` without a value, why allow the latter? It just makes it easier to make mistakes/ambiguity in the parsing. `nargs='?'` sort of works (you have to manually replace `None` with `8` when it happens, because if provided without an argument, it's not the default case, so it stores `None`), but it's a bad idea.

Comment: That seems ambiguous. How is the parser supposed to tell whether the thing after `-a` is a value for the `-a` option, or a positional argument? Whether or not argparse supports this, I don't think this is a good interface.

Comment: Play with `nargs='?'` and give it `default` and `const` parameters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40644096/argparse-differentiate-between-no-options-option-invoked-and-option-invoked

Comment: @user2357112: Well, `argparse` does accept `--` to mean "done with switches, positionals follow", but yeah, not everyone knows about that, and the ambiguity of `nargs='?'` (or worse, `'*'` or `'+'`), causes all sorts of problems.

Comment: thanks to those who answered. I changed it to:
parser.add_argument("-a", "--automatic", type=int, nargs="?", const="8")
and it worked right :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `nargs='?'` and `const=8`. From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs):

> ArgumentParser objects usually associate a single command-line argument with a single action to be taken. The nargs keyword argument associates a different number of command-line arguments with a single action.
>
> ...
>
> `'?'`. One argument will be consumed from the command line if possible, and produced as a single item. If no command-line argument is present, the value from [default](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#default) will be produced. Note that for optional arguments, there is an additional case - the option string is present but not followed by a command-line argument. In this case the value from [const](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#const) will be produced.

Comment: That's not enough, you need to pass `const` too, as @hpaulj notes, or passing the switch without a value stores `None`, not the `default` value.

Comment: Right you are, @ShadowRanger. I've updated my answer. Thanks to you and hpaulj for the correction.